# Why is pin 5 in the Ethernet connected to 3v3? is it safe to disconnect?

Tags: power, ethernet-port

Looking at the [pinout](http://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Raspberry-Pi-Schematics-R1.0.pdf) of the Pi's Ethernet, it looks like pin 5 is connected to the 3v3.

[image]

Why is it connected there? According to the [100Base-T Ethernet specification](http://pinouts.ru/Net/Ethernet10BaseT_pinout.shtml), that should be unconnected.

Does this serve any function? could it harm the device at the receiving end? would it be OK to disconnect (i.e. not have that wire in the Ethernet cord)?

Comment: I just checked and, I never realised this but the ether pins are not actually directly connected to the PCB pins. It uses magnetics to detect the signal.

Comment: This was the source of a delay in the original RPi shipments: http://www.raspberrypi.org/manufacturing-hiccup/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the 2 ends of the ethernet jack on the schematic you will see that pins 2 and 5 on the PCB side (left side) are connected to 3.3V to drive the integrated magnetics in the jack.

On the RJ-45 side pins 4,5,7,8 are all connected to ground via pins 9 and 10 on the PCB and not used for communication.

So on ethernet side it does not use the wires in the cord but those wires do not connect directly to any pins on the PCB.

Comment: 4.5.7.8 all connected to ground? via 9,10? and not used for coms? Can you explain then how the Ethernet works on this jack?

Comment: @ppumkin 4.5.7.8 are NOT connected to ground. They are connected to balance point of the Tx, Rx transformers which is bypassed to ground. This is to ensure balance and minimise noise. NOTE 100Base-T uses only 4 wires (2 pair).